# How can I test a protected URL (Authentication) on PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: authentication, pagespeed

I want to be able to test a protected URL that requires *Username* and *Password* using PageSpeedInsights.

I tried using `http(s)://user:password@server` but it doesn't looks to work!

Is it possible? Any idea?
Thanks!